# Ajax call to get number of members in Facebook group doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook-graph-api

A call to get the number of members in a Facebook group.

This works in every browser but IE.  Any idea why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            i=0;

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=My_apps_id&client_secret=SHHHHSECRETDONTTELLANYBODY&grant_type=client_credentials",
                //data: msg,
                dataType: "html",

           success: function(msg) {
                    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/242578930612/members?' + msg, function(data) {
                      var items = [];

                      $.each(data["data"], function(key, val) {              
                        i++;

                      });
                      $("#numMembers").text(i + " members");
                      console.log("members: " + i);
                    });
                }

             });
        });
```

Comment: Have you looked in the console to see what the error message is?

Comment: Nothing is set in the console at all.  I added a console.log to the top of the success function, before the $getJson call, and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE's `XDomainRequest` component has certain restrictions compared to the standardized `XMLHttpRequest` component - for instance, the protocol has to match between the page you're on, and the resource you're requesting.

Instead, use `FB.api`, which correctly deals with this, cross-browser.

That said - are you crazy performing the token exchange in the browser? I hope this is for a Phonegap app or similar :D.